# Quickblox linker error: operator delete(void*)", referenced from

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I'm creating a simple chat app with Quickblox.

So I added the project to XCode exactly like in this tutorial: http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework

QBUsers class worked just fine, but when I used QBChat I started to get linker errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
>         -[QBVideoChat initAudioCapture] in Quickblox(QBVideoChat.o)
>     "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
>         -[QBVideoChat initAudioCapture] in Quickblox(QBVideoChat.o)
>     "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
>         Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in Quickblox(QBVideoChat.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here's the line that causes the problem (if I comment it out, linker errors go away):

```
[[QBChat instance] setDelegate:self];
```

The class in which the problem occurs implements the following protocols:

```
<QBActionStatusDelegate, QBChatDelegate>
```

Here's the list of frameworks I imported to the project:

> -lxml2 -lresolv -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreVideo -framework Accelerate -framework CoreMedia -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreData -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework Quickblox -framework UIKit -framework Foundation

Comment: I included all the libraries that were in the tutorial...

Comment: If you really did, then try cleaning the project. Sometimes that helps with issues like this.

Comment: You're either missing the C++ standard library, or you have linked to the wrong C++ standard library (there are two of them). Try adding either libc++ or libstdc++.

Comment: Thanks Greg, it worked! Perhaps you can post this as an answer?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As it was suggested in comments by Greg Parker, I added libc++.dylib to the project and everything worked.

Comment: Yes, you can find this info here http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework as well

Comment: This worked for me with a different SDK, completely unrelated to Quickblox. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I added the libc++ and resolved

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16881635/1366033).  If you find an answer helpful, just vote it up (once you have permissions).  There is no need to repeat efforts

Answer (score 2):

For iOS9 do following in your application's target:
in build phases->Link Binary With Libraries ->search and add 'libstdc++.tbd'

In case you're trying to add this in a library target this won't work. the 'libstdc++.tbd' is not an object file so it can't be added into an objective-c library's target, it needs to be added in an application that wants to use the library.